# How do I keep a server connected as a volume after sleep?

Tags: macos, mount, network-shares, sleep

This would be in Mac OS X 10.6...

I know I can connect a server share as a volume and do so via a script so every time I boot up it gets mapped.

How can I make sure that same share is mapped after my computer comes out of sleep mode?  It seems like the connection gets dropped.  Can the same process map the drive for me when I boot up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TTry this:

Add

```
/- auto_afp
```

to /etc/auto_master.  Then, create /etc/auto_afp with a line like

```
/Volumes/MyShare -fstype=afp afp://computername/sharename
```

Make sure the permissions of auto_afp match auto_master

Take a the following for more info:
http://images.apple.com/business/docs/Autofs.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you let your computer in sleep for a short time, the connection should stay up. However, if you leave it for a longer time, the server will simply reset your connection, because otherwise all lost connections would hang on it forever, filling its memory. So you probably need to mount the network drive again after waking up. I don't know if there is a way to do it automatically in OS X. It's usually best practise to manually close everything that use ongoing network connections before you send your computer to sleep/hibernate, so no applications will crash because of lost connections.